# AWS CodeBuild trigger project on PR closed event

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codebuild

I'm using AWS CodeBuild and want to trigger project when my PR has been closed (WITHOUT being merged to base branch).

Terraform code example for regular merge event listed below

```
resource "aws_codebuild_webhook" "pr_closed" {
  project_name = "my_codebuild_project"

  filter_group {
    filter {
      type    = "EVENT"
      pattern = "PULL_REQUEST_MERGED"
    }
  }
}
```

Seems like there is no such event [here in documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-github-pull-request.html)

[image: allowed events]
Is there a way to make it happen?

Comment: Also looking for an answer to this, seems like it isn't possible with the events provided for CodeBuild which is a shame

Comment: I've been playing with this also, and I'm unable to get `PULL_REQUEST_MERGED` on PR closed. The workaround is to use CodePipeline webhook and setup jsonPath filters to look for pull request `action=closed`, something like `jsonPath: '$.action'`, `matchEquals: 'closed'`. The downside of this approach is that you don't get any PR context inside of the CodePipeline webhook.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question was asked some time ago, but for anyone finding this now - CodeBuild now supports for filtering on pull request closed events without a merge.

You can use a "PULL_REQUEST_CLOSED" for both your [GitHub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/github-webhook.html) and [BitBucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/bitbucket-webhook.html) webhook.